# Making program to read lines instead of single characters

Tags: c, for-loop, switch-statement, fgets

I have a problem. I've wrote a program that changes input according to chosen argument. Program works how I want it to work, but it wasnt accepted because it need to work on whole lines (with ***fgets*** I belive) instead of characters one by one. Second thing is it should print values in main function. 
I can't deal with none with that problems, could I get some help.

> main.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "WordTools.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char string[1000];
    size_t i = 0;

    while (i < sizeof string) {
        int ch = getchar();
        if (ch == EOF) break;
        string[i] = ch;
        i++;
    }
    string[i] = 0;

    switch (argc > 1 && argv[1][1]) {
    case 'l':
    case 'L':
        makeLower(string);
        break;
    case 'u':
    case 'U':
        break;
    case 'c':
    case 'C':
        makeChange(string);
        break;
    case 'n':
    case 'N':
        makeName(string);
        break;
    default:
        makeUpper(string);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> WordTools.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "WordTools.h"

void makeLower(char *s) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++){
        s[i] = tolower(s[i]);
    }
    printf("%s", s);
}

void makeUpper(char *s) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++){
        s[i] = toupper(s[i]);
    }
    printf("%s", s);
}

void makeChange(char *s) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if ((s[i] >= 65) && (s[i] <= 90)) s[i] = tolower(s[i]);
        else if ((s[i] >= 97) && (s[i] <= 122)) s[i] = toupper(s[i]);
    }
    printf("%s", s);
}

void makeName(char *s) {
    int i;
    s[0]=toupper(s[0]);
    for(i = 1; s[i] != '\0'; i++){
        s[i] = tolower(s[i]);
    }
    printf("%s", s);
}
```

Comment: Yes you need `fgets`. Show your code using `fgets` and then ask specific questions if you have difficulties. Not directly related to your question: avoid "magic"  numbers such as `65` or `97` but use rather `'A'` or `'a'`.

Comment: result of `argc > 1 && argv[1][1]` is `1` or `0`.

Comment: Don't use `((s[i] >= 65) && (s[i] <= 90))` or even `((s[i] >= 'A') && (s[i] <= 'Z'))`. That's not portable, nor standard-compliant C. Use `islower()` and `isupper()`.  And you can use [`getline()` for reading lines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html).  It won't have a hardcoded limit on line length.

Comment: Still not working. Seems I have to modify somehow the tools function but i dont know how.

Comment: `char option = ' '; if(argc > 1 && argv[1][1]) option = argv[1][1]; switch(option){... }` and `case 'U':
        break;` --> `case 'U':makeUpper(string);
        break;`